# How to change owner of site on Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

How to change owner of site on Google Analyics?

My site was maintained before by some company (Company A) that created site, targets in Google Analytics. But now my site maintain another company (Company B) that havent access to Google Analytics.

Can I transfer site, data, targets from old account GA to new account (Company B)? I havent access to old account (bcs owner is another company (Company A), I dont collaborate with them).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to gain access to the old account and follow the account transfer process: https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/44500?hl=en

If you don't have access or can't gain access, the best you can do is create a new account with this property and add the new code to your website, thus losing your past data.

Answer (score 0):

The process to [move a Google Analytics property](https://tillison.co.uk/blog/how-to-move-a-google-analytics-property-to-another-account/) is a bit clunky, but pretty slick once you've had to do it a few times.

1. A user will need Admin access to the Google Analytics ACCOUNT where the Property is currently, AND Admin access to another Google Analytics Account (create a new one if you need to) where you want to move the Analytics Property to.
2. Once you have Admin access to both, head in to the Property Settings and click, "move account".
3. On completion, you can update the access rights to your Google Account, removing access as necessary.

Your Analytics Property will be complete with all of the historic data, configuration and user access rights.

There's a video showing the process here too: https://youtu.be/m_F3qmSTIl0